# Grails Project with React/Flux

Tags: grails, flux, refluxjs

I am currently working on a project in which we are having a React/Flux UI being developed for us. I am being told that the UI code needs to be converted into GSPs and put into a Grails Project, to work with our backend. I feel like moving the UI into GSPs will nullify the use of our Flux implementation(Reflux).

My initial thought is that this is wrong and I have not found any use of Grails and Flux through searching.

Answer (score 2):

I'm involved with a production Grails application which uses React as it's front-end. There's no need to "convert" the React/Flux code into GSP - in fact that would largely sacrifice the benefits of the React UI. There's no need- Grails is very well suited to provide a [robust Restful backend](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html) to a React (or Angular, or any other JS framework) application.

Depending on your application needs, you will probably want to provide a restful API for the front-end to consume/post as needed. Use `URLMappings.groovy` to specify endpoints that the React app can access. You will likely choose to use JSON as the medium to send data to the React app - [Grails' JSON views](http://grails.github.io/grails-views/latest/) are a fast, flexible and straightforward means to render Grails domain objects or other data to a JSON payload.

There shouldn't be anything Grails-specifc regarding Flux - use it to manage and mutate your state in the React application, perhaps by making rest calls from your Flux dispatcher (or action creator) to the Grails backend to retrieve data and update your Flux store.

Regarding GSP, my recommendation is to simply have a barebones GSP view off your main controller, which simply loads the Javascript needed to run your React app. If you are using a module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io), this can be as simple as linking your `bundle.js` file into your view and providing the root element specified in your top-level component:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app"></div>
  <asset:javascript src="bundle.js"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that for this to work, you must be outputting your `webpack` bundle into `grails-app/assets/javascripts`, which I find to be the simplest way to load the React application in a Grails app. Using this approach, there's no need to load React, Flux or other related libraries into Grails directly - just build your project using the standard JS toolchain (using `npm`/`package.json` to manage your dependencies), and process/bundle the entire application into a plain JS bundle that can be loaded by the Grails asset-pipeline.

React makes a great choice as a view-focused Javascript library that doesn't make a lot of assumptions about your backend architecture. With a solid restful api based on Grails, and some intelligent choices about tooling and project structure, React is a great fit for a modern, single-page Javascript UI in a Grails app.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the use of GSP nullify the use of React or Flux? GSP is just a server-side processing language that renders HTML. Last I checked React and Flux make good use of HTML for a great number of things in combination with Javascript.

You can use them together without any issues. How, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are being told wrong. GSPs are Java servlets. The only reason to mix React with a server-side technology is for an isomorphic application, where you would compile your JS prior to returning/pushing it to the client. In which case, you would need to create something akin to a Rhino-based servlet. Otherwise, treat it as you would treat any other static asset.